# how can i see object in camera view without scanning target image?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am working on augmented reality . And i have started with vuforia. Demo project is working perfectly.

My question is how can i see object in camera view without scanning target image? That 3d model will be fixed. But i want it to be set in camera view and perform operation on it like zoom , rotate etc.

Currently in demo , i have one target image stored in cloud database,. By scanning that image, 3d model is seen in our camera view.

But now i want my selected 3d model to be set in camera view and adjust it as per my requirement.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but when you say "camera view", do you mean the phone's actual physical camera? (Rather than the rendered screen.) If so, Unity doesn't have any API to access the device camera, but there are surely native plugins that can grab images from the device hardware.

Comment: Yea I am talking about device camera.  You can see https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ar.augment&hl=en . Here we have 3d model in store department.

Comment: Check this question out, I believe it's asking the same thing: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/550729/how-to-access-device-iphoneandroid-native-camera.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your problem completely.If you need this for GUI operations you can use [OnGUI](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnGUI.html).
But if you want persistent 3D Object you can change `World Center Mode`-> `FIRST_TARGET` to `CAMERA` in `QCARBehaviour` script which is in `ARCamera` object. Then Add Your model and move it to `ARCamera`'s view.